# Problem creating a new framework project in Zend Studio

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I have a problem when creating a New Framework project in Zend Studio. I'm new to Zend Studio, using Zend Studio ver.7.1.0.

When creating a new Zend framework project (Zend Server is successfully installed), it will not create the 'application' or 'public' folders.

In my previous test project these were created automatically. But here the only things being created are

- Javascript Resources
- PHP Include Path
- PHP Language Library

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Make shure the option `Zend Framework default project structure` is activated under `project layout`. You can check out `Full featured Zend Framework and Dojo Project` as well, but that may generate a little too much.

[image]

Comment: Thanx for reply Guy of Doom! 
yes, I am sure it. But that folders is not generated. :(

Comment: Most first time those folders generate without any issue. But thereafter they will not generating.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact the same problem !
The answer is simple .

It's because of windows 7 permissions.

Just go to your localhost folder, It's

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs
```

since you are using Zend server.
Right click on it and select "WRITE" permission for users.
Just to make sure I selected all permissions for all categories.

And next time I've created my Zend framework project,it created the structure as well !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of the existing basic projects and then remove the small amount of stuff that you don't need.  See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Note you could also try zf tool and do "zf create project"

Comment: ZF is working. (zf show verion -> return version)But 'zf create project proname' gives error.
However finally I install 7.1.1 beta version. Its working perfect yet.
:)

Thanx for all!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years ago, but I thought I'd give an answer as to how I solved this exact same problem. I'm only posting this answer here since a search for this problem turned up near the top of the google results, so I'm not posting for some useless SO points.

In the past, I would create ZF projects in Zend Studio and it would create for me a basic application structure with public, application, library, etc. folders. One day I accidentally deleted ZFDoctrine which I had in my Zend Framework path. Weeks later, when I went to create a new ZF project, Zend Studio created the new project without the familiar basic application structure. I did not get any error or warning so I tried to create the same project using zf Zend tool. At the command line, I received several warnings that ZFDoctrine would not load. So I put ZFDoctrine back in my library path and the problem disappeared. So long story short, it's probably something in the library path.